# ld: Final link Failed: Memory exhausted while building Linux kernel 5.8.9

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I am trying to compile Linux Kernel 5.8.9 on Ubuntu 16.04 installed on VirtualBox ( specifications: 22 + 3 GB, Memory : 2 GB). After successfully making the .config file using `make menuconfig`, I compiled it using `make`. The compilation ran for around 100 minutes and stopped abruptly displaying error memory exhausted. How can I remove this error?

Comment: How much memory do you have on your system?   "Memory exhausted" tends to be during linking and is very memory intensive.  This has nothing to do with disk usage, afaik.

Comment: If you can't add memory to your virtual machine you can at least add a swap area to guest linux installation, e.g. by adding a swapfile. Some hints here: https://linuxize.com/post/create-a-linux-swap-file/

Comment: @GiuseppeGuerrini swap is so slow, it will probably be faster to just save up for more RAM, buy it, and install it into your computer then try compiling again. Using gold instead of ld might help with memory usage somewhat if you really are desperate to use current setup and swapfile... Also making sure that you aren't compiling in parallel (each make job naturally uses more memory) is a good idea too. One more memory hog might be debug build, make sure you're compiling for release without debug symbols that can weigh a lot.

Comment: @Yamirui of course, it depends on Harsh's preferences. If it's a one-time compilation/test it may be worth to just add swap and wait... If it's a routine job, it's probably better to increase the RAM configuration in VM (and perhaps in real machine, :-( ).If, as Ewong said, the error happens at the final link step, disabling parallel compilation doesn't help much.

Comment: Adding a swap area worked. Thanks @GiuseppeGuerrini !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Giuseppe, add a swap area to the Linux installation with a suitable Swapify value(default is 60, which works for most of the cases). Further instructions for adding a swap area can be found [here](https://linuxize.com/post/create-a-linux-swap-file/)